# c# creating msc file

Tags: c#-4.0, mmc, snap-in

How can I create *.msc file? I see a lot of articles about creating snap-in's.

My goal is to create msc file so people can double click it and bring defined snap-in

Thanks

Comment: .msc files are Management Console files which are used to "save" a MMC config, ie, all the loaded snapins for that instance. They do not include any snap-in implementations

Comment: So, if I want to create shortcut for snap in, how it's can be done?

Comment: Well, if you manually add your snap-in to MMC, then choose save as to save the current "setup". I assume that when your snapin is registered on a different PC, running MMC via the .msc file should probably work just fine.

Comment: It's kinda what i am doing now, and not entirely happy with it, since sometimes i need to alter msc configuration, depending on machine.. Anyways, thanks a lot for answer!

Comment: Msc files are just plain xml, you might be able to create them programmatically to suit your needs. Good luck

Answer (score -2):

open the **MMC** and import your snap in from

> FILE>Add/Remove Snap

then

> File>Save As

you get what you want. BTW, you could rename the console, change icon.. in the

> File>Options